# How to initialize char pointer in order to use it frequently in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to write a method that get substring (first word before space) in a string line 
....My code:

```
char* getCommand(char* commandLine)
    {
     int index = 0;
     char* command = {0};
     command = malloc(1000);   

     printf("%d\n",(int)strlen(command));

     printf("%s\n", command);

     while(commandLine[index]!=' ')
     {
         command[index]=commandLine[index];
         index++;
     }
     return (char *)command;
    }


    while(){
       printf("%s\n",getCommand(cmd)); // cmd is  char cmd[MAX_CMD_LENGTH];
     }
```

it works fine but it gives me error :

malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)-   >bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0)   || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: `strlen(NULL)` -> crash, most likely...

Comment: Lots of issues here.  you are copying data into command, which has no storage allocated to it. You may want to do some more reading on pointers and memory allocation in C.

Comment: sorry, there's no NULL, i edited it...it works fine but after that it has problems.

Comment: `strlen(<unitialized>)` isn't any better. Maybe you meant to take `strlen(commandLine)`?

Comment: You're relying on undefined behavior by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. Also, what if there are no spaces in the command?

Comment: "got it?!"? - No, "cryptic" doesn't even begin to describe that attempt at a problem statement.

Comment: _.it works fine  but after that it has problems_.  That's an indication of undefined behavior.  If command happens to be created at a place in memory where the conditions are ***just right***, then you might get some _expected_ response, for awhile.  You have to create, initialize then allocate memory if you want it to give expected responses all the time.  `char* command = {0};`, then:  `command = malloc(some_size_t_value);`

Comment: it worked with malloc, but it stopped after while, what's the best value to put in some_size_t_value?..thank you.

Comment: I do not see a single `malloc()` statement in your code snippet.  It is difficult (impossible really) to address your problem with any accuracy, if you do not include all of the relevant information.  ***[Please Read This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)***, modify your question to comply, and the responses you get will be more helpful.  By the way, in case you did not know it, the phrase "_Got it?!_" can be easily misinterpreted to convey impatience and anger.  Most people do not respond well to either. (even when followed by a _thank you_)

Comment: i tried malloc() after your comment sir, not before the question, and yes after i posted "got it?" i felt bad about it but i just want to know if i helped you understanding my question well, sorry all.

Comment: Add the malloc back into your question, by all means.  The question, in its current state, needs to be a minimal, but complete, representation of the code necessary to convey your expectations, and the issue you are asking about.  Edit your question to include these, and I suspect it will be re-opened.  (I have already voted that way, since I saw your last edit.)  By the way, comments on this site can be deleted if you would prefer something you say not been seen again :)  Look for the little red x to the right of your comment.

Comment: Okay, i'll edit it after that, i thought about deleting it but all comments below it metnioned that expression :D so it's useless to delete it but i deleted it any way.

Answer (score 2):

These statements

```
 char* command;

 printf("%d\n",(int)strlen(command));

 printf("%s\n", command);
```

have no sense because variable command has an unspecified value.

And it is a bad idea to use a global variable like `argsOffset`
Also it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Take into account that you could use standard C function `strtok` decalred in header `<string.h>` to split the original string into words.

If I have understood correctly what you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

char * getCommand( char *commandLine )
{
    static char *p;
    char *q;

    if ( commandLine ) p = commandLine;


    while ( isblank( *p ) ) ++p;
    q = p;

    while ( *p && !isblank( *p ) ) ++p;

    return q;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello Mohamed Seif";

    char *p = getCommand( s );

    while ( *p )
    {
        while ( *p && !isblank( *p ) ) printf( "%c", *p++ );
        puts( "" );

        p = getCommand( NULL );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello
Mohamed
Seif
```

If you want that the function would return a new zero-terminated string then you need to allocate it. Its size will be `p - q + 1`

Comment: I think OP is trying to extract the first part of the string until a space.

Comment: I think he wanted to put commandLine into strlen() function

Comment: i'm trying to get the first word before space character in the commandLine string.
the problem is that first of all command is zero length and gets the first word right.
then the second loop comes, second input, command supposed to be initialized again and lenght is zero again but it yet has the previous input word.

Comment: i modified the code to the last code now, it gives me segmentation fault (code dumped) error!!

Comment: @Mohamed Seif See my updated post.

Comment: @Drew McGowen Is not what I wrote he wants, is it?

Comment: it works well, but i want to get my code worked..not copying and paste a code...i appreciate it sir :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was referring to your statement "Also it is not clear what you are trying to do."

Comment: @Drew McGowen It is true. I do not understand this.:)

Comment: @Mohamed Seif The better solution for you is to investigate my code.:)